# Nginx configuration for multiple static sites on same server instance

Tags: nginx, vue.js, vue-router, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have three static sites. I am using Vue 2 and running build for each folder.

I want to host all three static files on the same server instance. Right now I don't have domain so i want to host on server's IP itself.

I have folder in html/www folder

```
first_folder
second_folder
third_folder
```

All the above three folders have index.html file in it.

Let's say that I have an IP address 3.12.178.229

I want to access folders like

```
http://3.12.178.229     // i.e path for first_folder
http://3.12.178.229/second_path    // i.e path for second_folder
http://3.12.178.229/third_path     // i.e path for third_folder
```

I am able to access the index.html file which first_folder has, but when I am trying to access second_folder using IP http://3.12.178.229/second_folder It does not show anything.

```
{
   listen 80;
   server_name 3.12.178.229;

   location / {
     root path_to_first_folder/first_folder; // I am able to access this
     index  index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

   location /second_path {
     root path_to_first_folder/second_folder; // I am able to access this

     index  index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

   location /third_path {
     root path_to_first_folder/third_folder; // I am able to access this

     index  index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pathname of the requested file is constructed by concatenating the value of `root` directive with the URI. So you can only use `root` with subfolders if (for example) `second_path` and `second_folder` is actually the same name. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

For example:

```
location /foo {
    root /path/to/root;
}
```

The URI `/foo/index.html` is located at `/path/to/root/foo/index.html`

---

Where `second_path` and `second_folder` are different names, you will need to use the `alias` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location /foo {
    alias /path/to/root/bar;
}
```

The URI `/foo/index.html` is located at `/path/to/root/bar/index.html`